# The maximum amount of substance that can completely evaporate in a given container

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, equilibrium

As you know when we have given substance in an empty container then the substance would evaporate until and equilibrium is attained between the substance and it's vapour phase. In due process the original phase of the substance will decrease in amount.

So I was thinking if we have initially $n_o$ moles of substance and at equilibrium it reduces to $n$. Then:

- what should be the value of $n_o$ if $n$ tends to zero?
- does this $n_o$ depend on the volume of container?

Comment: If $n_0$ is the initial amount would this not be a constant that you chose?

Comment: Perhaps in the last line OP means whether the *limit* of $n_0$ depends on the container